# About a PostgreSQL query that never ends

Tags: postgresql

I have a problem with a query, the following runs in PostgreSQL 
but never ends. Do you have any suggestion ?

```
WITH tmp1 AS (
  SELECT istante, produzione,
       CAST (CAST (produzione AS FLOAT) / 12000 AS NUMERIC(6,2)) AS proden,
       CAST (CAST (consumo AS FLOAT) / 12000 AS NUMERIC(6,2)) AS consen
  FROM ftv1 
  ), tmp2 AS (
  SELECT LEAST(proden, consen) AS aconsen 
  FROM tmp1
  )
SELECT tmp1.istante, tmp1.proden, tmp1.consen, 
       (tmp1.consen - tmp2.aconsen) AS enconsen
FROM tmp1, tmp2;
```

Comment: How many rows does your table have and how long are you waiting before it *never ends*?

Comment: Select FROM tmp1, tmp2 statement works as Cartesian join. Because of which it is not completing. Please give proper join condition

Comment: There is no any WHERE clause that defines a joining condition of `ftv1` and  `tmp2`, so actually it it a cross join which combinse all rows from the first table with all rows from the second table. If the first table contains for example 10.000 rows and the second one has 20.000 rows, then the cross join produces 10000 x 20000 = 200000000 rows - it must take some time (maybe a dozen days, or even a couple of weeks, but most likely until a disk space will be exhausted, because RDBMS saves all generated rows on the disk in the temporary table).

Comment: `select count(*) as exact_count from ftv1_en;` gives 218233. It is the first time i really need a database, excuse my ignorance on the subject. Thank you for clarification about Cartesian and FROM v1, v2. Do you have any book to suggest to understand how a RDBMS solves queries, especially Postgres? Right now for me it is just a black box.

Comment: `... from ftv1;` but ok, same result

Comment: Anyhow, I was curious about your statement so I checked and i re-run the query keeping `top` and `watch -n 1 df` running. The CPU load never goes larger than 2%, memory use never more than 4%. And there seems to be not significant disk use. So, at least in a little Debian 8 v.m. running psql 9.4.12 (accessed remotely) there is no resource usage explosion.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below

```
WITH tmp1 AS (
  SELECT istante, produzione,
       CAST (CAST (produzione AS FLOAT) / 12000 AS NUMERIC(6,2)) AS proden,
       CAST (CAST (consumo AS FLOAT) / 12000 AS NUMERIC(6,2)) AS consen
  FROM ftv1 
  ), tmp2 AS (
  SELECT istante,LEAST(proden, consen) AS aconsen 
  FROM tmp1
  )
SELECT t1.istante, t1.proden, t1.consen, 
       (t1.consen - t2.aconsen) AS enconsen
FROM tmp1 t1
join  tmp2 t2
on t1.istante = t2.istante;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your query is solved in about 8 minutes (in a little Debian virtual machine). The release I just posted takes about 3-4 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Before seeing your answers I solved with the code below, anyway now I know why this works, no cartesian product. Thank you all for your assistance.

```
WITH tmp1 AS (
  SELECT istante, produzione,
       (CAST (produzione AS FLOAT) / 12000) AS proden,
       (CAST (consumo AS FLOAT) / 12000) AS consen
  FROM ftv1 
  ), tmp2 AS (
  SELECT istante, produzione, proden, consen, 
         LEAST(proden, consen) AS aconsen 
  FROM tmp1
  )
SELECT istante, proden, consen, aconsen, 
       (consen - aconsen)  AS enconsen,
       GREATEST(proden - consen, 0) as senten
FROM tmp2;
```